# using Lame dll in Unity3d

Tags: dll, unity-game-engine, dllimport, lame

I am trying to use LAME in Unity3d on OS X with Mono c#. I dragged the Lame_enc.dll in but when the wrapper tries to find it, it doesn't and i get

```
DllNotFoundException: Lame_enc.dll
Yeti.MMedia.Mp3.Mp3Writer..ctor (System.IO.Stream Output, WaveLib.WaveFormat InputDataFormat, Yeti.Lame.BE_CONFIG Mp3Config) (at Assets/Helping Libraries/Lame/Mp3Writer.cs:82)
```

The problem from what i see, it when i try to 'link' some static methods to the dll:

```
 [DllImport("Lame_enc.dll")]
    public static extern uint beInitStream(BE_CONFIG pbeConfig, ref uint dwSamples, ref uint dwBufferSize, ref uint phbeStream);
```

I know that in order to see dll, on Windows, the dll needs to be in the same folder as the .exe file, but Unity being a multiplatform solution, i don't know how i can tell it where it is.

I've placed the dll in my project root folder, in the Library, in the Editor, but no luck!

Comment: Given that it's a plugin (in Unity's terms), it should be in a folder named "Plugins". See if that does the trick.

Comment: @Bart i've tried it, it doesn't work.

Answer (score 0):

Just remove the ".dll",it will work well in Editor,but won't work on mobile phone.I removed the using xxx.window and some unused files,but still the output file xx.mp3 only has 44B.